# Is it possible to synchronize edits made on a local word doc editor to its central repository document(db document) on saving the doc locally?

Tags: java, version-control, ms-word, synchronization

I need to implement a java application on MSWord Document management(or for any Text Doc Editor) and in that the word documents will be stored in a central repository like database or in server.Many users will be handling the documents, which requires complete version controlling. All the edits/changes made should be saved in the central document.

My question is, **is it possible to save the changes on a central document(located in  database) after opening and editing it on a local document editor?** i mean, while accessing and editing the central document, i think they will be doing that on a local copy and how just a document save action can sync that change to the central copy? Is there a way to implement it through code, something like on **save event trigger**?

All the changes that users make in their copy should be updated on the central copy. I plan to implement something like working of google docs in this kind of a scenario. Inviting your valuable suggestions and useful links if any?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this school assignment or something? Because if this is "real work", then you should use some existing VCS...

Comment: This is a "real work" and yes, I need to use a VCS like svn. Got some requirements and I am researching on the best ways to implement this

Comment: The UI design part is not yet clear, and on the client's initial requirement its like they need to see the word docs in repository, and on accessing and editing that(I think at this stage each user is getting a local copy and making edits on that). If its so, then I think on saving after the edits or on closing the docs, the local copy should be synchronised with repository and needs to be committed. The client is not intending to have a feature to upload the doc after edits. Is it possible to sync and commit such a local copy back to repository on doc save or on closing the doc?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can [listen to the File System and get notifications when files change](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) so in theory you could use this to see when the document has been edited and upload it to the server.

However you'd need to solve these problems:

- If the Java application closes/crashes while Word is open, nothing will detected a save and the user's changes to their document will get lost and they will have no indication why.
- People save Word Documents all the time when editing them so not to lose data, but they'd only want the final save checked in as their revision.
- Multiple users editing the same document at the same time and overwriting each other's changes.
- There's no way in a silent automatic process for users to enter comments describing their changes.

It may be preferable to have a manual check-in/check-out upload/download process rather than trying to do it all automatically.

Comment: Thanks...I will check that...But the initial requirement is something without having an upload/download option. But not sure how to do this otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd consider:

A (Java in your case) GUI application, which shows the documents in central repository, and allows launching Word (or whatever) to edit, which then checks out and also locks the document in the repository. Then when Word (or whatever) process exits, changes are committed (possibly after a popup confirmation dialog, where user could choose to discard their edits, or be required to enter a comment about their change) and repository lock on the file removed.

Then you also need some mechanism to handle stale locks (for example, when user PC got shut down / crashed without releasing the lock). Be sure to use a VCS which works well with binary files, and which supports file locking at server side, and code the app so that you can easily change the VCS software if your first choice isn't ideal.

So your Java app might do most of it's work by execution other programs (VCS binaries for checking out / locking / committing, GUI application for editing). While the app seems fairly simple, it might still be worth it to look at something like [Netbeans RCP](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/) or [Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform) and build your app on top of such a platform. I haven't actually used them myself, so take that as an idea to consider and research, not as a recommendation.